# Java RMI. ¿es posible cargar una clase desde el cliente que no esté declarada en el servidor?

Tags: java

Estoy iniciandome en Java RMI...
Trataré de explicarme lo mejor posible.
intento ejecutar una clase que sólo se encuentra en el lado cliente y quisiera cargarla al lado del servidor para que se ejecute allí es posible?

Dispulpe si no me explico bien aqui un ejemplo que encontre:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);
InterfaceRemota objetoRemoto = (InterfaceRemota) registry.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/ObjetoRemoto");
System.out.println(objetoRemoto.suma(new Sumando(2, 3)));
```

sumando(int a, int b) se encueantra en el lado servidor y funciona bien

lo que intento es desde el cliente pasar otra clase que contenga por ejemplo multiplicar(int a, int b) que no esté en el lado servidor

Comment: De ser posible me podrian dar algun ejemplo, de antemano gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta este mas completa. No se entiende lo que necesitas. Si necesitas agregar informacion, usa el boton [edit] y agrega la informacion en la pregunta...

Comment: Dispulpe si no me explico bien aqui un ejemplo que encontre: